# Wrap Vimeo URL with Player using JS/Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, wordpress, plugins, vimeo

I've started developing a site at: http://joshrodg.com/isbellfilms2/

I have a WordPress plugin that generates a pricing table. I like the way the plugin works and functions for the user, but needed to tweak one thing.

The plugin has a place for a description, which I don't have, but I would like to add a video instead.

I recognize this is a WordPress website, but the issue I am having is with my scripting.

What I am trying to do is find the Vimeo URL and pass that into a player.

I found a piece of code, tweaked it a bit, but it's not quite working.

The JS I am using looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var classSelector = document.querySelectorAll('.rpt_description');
        var vimeoRegEx = /(?:http?s?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:vimeo\.com)\/?(.+)/g;
        var vimeoEmbed = '<div class="embed-container"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/$1" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div>';

        array.prototype.forEach.call(classSelector, function(el) {
            if (vimeoRegEx.test(el.innerHTML)) {
                el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(vimeoRegEx, vimeoEmbed);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The code the plugin outputs with the Vimeo URLs:

```
<div class="rpt_plan rpt_plan_ori rpt_plan_0  ">
    <div style="text-align: center; height: 15px;" class="rpt_title rpt_title_0">The Family Yearbook Film</div>
    <div class="rpt_head rpt_head_0" style="height: 250px;">
        <div class="rpt_recurrence rpt_recurrence_0">(Yearly)</div>
        <div class="rpt_price rpt_price_0"><span class="rpt_currency"></span>$350</div>
        <div style="color:#3ac893;" class="rpt_subtitle rpt_subtitle_0">Stay up to date with your changing family for an entire year.</div>
        <div class="rpt_description rpt_description_0">https://www.vimeo.com/320417542</div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rpt_features rpt_features_0" style="height: 183px;">
        <div style="color:black;" class="rpt_feature rpt_feature_0-0">A 3-5 min film every 3 months (4 total films)</div>
        <div style="color:black;" class="rpt_feature rpt_feature_0-1">Plus one Keepsake film</div>
        <div style="color:black;" class="rpt_feature rpt_feature_0-2">30% off discount on any additional films you purchase that year.</div>
        <div style="color:black;" class="rpt_feature rpt_feature_0-3">Upload 30-450 clips</div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <a target="_self" href="https://isbellfamilyfilms.com/#order-form" style="background:#3ac893" class="rpt_foot rpt_foot_0">Add to Cart</a>
</div>
```

The regex finds the URL and the JS takes the URL and passes it to the player, something just isn't quite right. I made sure that this JS executes before the plugin, but I have tried it both ways.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally forgot the jQuery reference, so embarrassing! Just needed to add this line before my JS code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

I also had to capitalize `Array`

Hope this helps someone!
Josh